# Having HMENU, how to enumerate menu items and invoke one programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to do that without calling any kind of GUI functions (like `TrackPopupMenuEx`), entirely programmatically?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use automation

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: no, not in my case.

Comment: It's unusual for a program's menus not to be automatable. I'm curious, why is that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: maybe I didn't understand what kind of automation you're talking about, but if nothing else that would be clumsy. Also, turned out I didn't specify my task well enough in the question, and the solution was much easier than I expected (doesn't even involve posting messages). The menu in question is a shell context menu, and everything I need was achieved with the `IContextMenu` interface and its method `InvokeCommand`.

Comment: Automation is not clumsy. The approach you were attempting certainly is clumsy. Telling us about the real problem would have avoided all the confusion and saved everyone time. You want to invoke items on a shell context menu? Why didn't you say so?! Totally different question and trivially easy to solve.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: When posting the question, I did not realize it was important. To ask the right question one must know half the answer :)

Comment: That's true enough. Windows is a very rich environment so generally some context will help answers steer you to solutions that you might not otherwise realise exist.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the `HMENU` of the top level menu, you can use [`GetMenuItemCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647978(v=vs.85).aspx) to find out how many items are on the menu, and then use [`GetMenuItemID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647979(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the ID associated with each item. Once you have the ID, you can `PostMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, ID, 0)` to simulate a click.

If the application amends its menu items dynamically, you may first need to `SendMessage` a dummy `WM_INITMENU` and `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` to the owing window so that it can adjust the menu items before you enumerate them.

Comment: The tricky part is knowing which `HWND` to post to, as it may not be the app's main window. You have to post to whatever `HWND` has been passed to `SetMenu()` or `TrackPopupMenu/Ex()`, since that the `HWND` that receives the messages related to that menu.